# Is there anything I'm missing in ajax

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller

Here is the code i've used it's always going to error but working call back but cant able to read any data always showing undefined

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:59817/api/patients?callback=?",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        debugger;
        console.log(data);
    },success: function (){},error: function (){}
    }
)
```

Comment: You need to provide more context around what you are doing and any server side code you are requesting. Undefined typically means a variable has not been set, in this case data.

Comment: I'm running a local api and calling it in mvc view using that code. first it showing missing Cors error then started working as shown because i've seen datatype:jsonp will solve that cors error. Now Cors error removed but can't able to go to success.

Comment: Why is this tagged "C#"?

Comment: adding jsonp will not just fix the issue. if you are running this from localhost CORS should be ok. Can you debug the server side code to see what is going on there? If you are using VS you should be able to set a breakpoint. You may need to remporarily add the projects into the same solution.

Answer (score -1):

here is A sample of Jquery Ajax, Try it

```js
            $.ajax({
                url: "Url/" + value,
                type: "Get",//Or Post,Put
                data: {dataname: value}
            }).done(function(response){
                alert("Response is: " + response);
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```